# Order of subgroup of symmetric group $S_n$

Tags: group-theory, symmetric-groups

> $H=\{\sigma \in S_n :\sigma(3)=3\}$

where $S_n$ is the symmetric group of degree $n$. We need to find the order of the subgroup $H$.
My book has the answer 2.

*But my intuition says that by fixing $3$, 
we can permute the rest of the $n-1$ symbols, thus we should have $(n-1)!$ as the order of $H$.*

Is that the correct way to think?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  In fact, your argument shows that $H$ is isomorphic to $S_{n-1}$.  Are you sure that your text wasn't thinking about the case $n=3$?

Comment: @IuIu Thank you for confirming. Yes surely my book contains a typo. Had it asked for $S_3$, the answer should have been surely 2.

Comment: Which textbook are you referring to?

Comment: @Shaun Its a question from our university module motivated from *Contemporary Abstract Algebra*